# C-Leitura de uma quantidade específica de caracteres

Tags: c, string

Olá, pessoal!
Sou apenas um iniciante no mundo da programação e estou enfrentando o seguinte problema:
Gostaria de ler o nome de um jogador que deve ter no mínimo 1 e no máximo 10 caracteres, a princípio pensei em criar um vetor de caracteres maior, como por exemplo 100, ler e fazer a verificação, mas ainda sim isso não garantiria que o usuário não entraria com um nome maior do que 100, não é? Então comecei a me perguntar se conseguiria fazer essa leitura de alguma maneira genérica. Depois de pesquisar e tentar algumas coisas consegui algo próximo do que queria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int tamanho;
    char nome_do_jogador[13];

    printf("Digite seu nickname:\n(Entre 1 e 10 caracteres!)\n");
    //setbuf(stdin, NULL); NÃO FUNCIONOU, ENTÃO OPTEI POR fflush
    fflush(stdin); //LIMPA O BUFFER DO TECLADO
    fscanf(stdin, "%12[^\n]", nome_do_jogador); //LE 12 CARACTERES ATE ENCONTRAR UMA QUEBRA DE LINHA
    tamanho=strlen(nome_do_jogador);

    while(tamanho>10 || tamanho<1)
    {
        printf("Entrada invalida!\n");
        printf("Digite seu nickname:\n(Entre 1 e 10 caracteres!)\n");
        //setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        fflush(stdin); //LIMPA O BUFFER DO TECLADO
        fscanf(stdin, "%12[^\n]", nome_do_jogador); 
        tamanho=strlen(nome_do_jogador);
    }
    printf("O nickname e: %s", nome_do_jogador);
    return 0;
}
```

Consegui fazer funcionar no Windows com GCC 7.3.0, mas não no Linux também com o GCC, mas não me lembro qual a versão no momento.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso de maneira genérica e que consiga manter multiplataforma?

Abraços!

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem o problema, se você mandar ler só 10 caracteres isso será respeitado (geralmente usa-se o `fgets()` se for algo mais complexo, mas um nome simples e sem espaço o `scanf()` resolve bem). `fflush(stdin)` não é potável e é documentado que não funciona para o que as pessoas acham que ele funciona, não sei porque usam isso. Esse código é muito repetitivo, dá para fazer isso de forma muito mais simples. E há ineficiências também, mas se fizer certo ela some sozinha. Acho que está tentando arrumar um problema causado por outro problema, conserte o problema original.

Comment: Funcionando no Linux: https://ideone.com/B831RS

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` representa comportamento indefinido em linux, e consequentemente não limpa o buffer do teclado. Se fizer a leitura com um buffer grande o suficiente (tipo 1024) o problema resolve-se só por si.